# Easy food and difficult ingredients

Tags: word-choice

Do "easy food" and "difficult ingredients"  sound natural? I think "from" is wrong.

"I don't like cooking easy food. I like cooking from difficult ingredients."

Perhaps "I like cooking using difficult ingredients."

Comment: I'd say "I like cooking *with* difficult ingredients". I don't think I'd naturally use 'difficult' though.

Comment: We usually say *cooking with* or *cooking using*, but what is a "difficult ingredient"?

Comment: @stangdon One that takes a lot of fiddly preparation, and / or needs to be cooked with precise timing and technique. Perhaps getting a risotto right, or making a roux, as opposed to just slapping a steak on a griddle for a few minutes.

Comment: @PrimeMover - But that describes the dish, not the ingredients!

Comment: @KateBunting Oh all right, squid then.

Comment: I'd describe squid as "faffy", but I'm not sure I'd use it in formal writing!

Comment: If you want to use 'difficult', 'fiddly' or 'tricky', you might consider using 'recipes'. I.e. "I like cooking difficult recipes".

Comment: Or dishes. "I like cooking complex dishes".

Comment: The ingredient itself isn't difficult, but you could describe actions involving the ingredient as difficult.  For instance - "I like to cook with morel mushrooms, but they are difficult to find." or "I like to eat puffer fish, but it is difficult to prepare."

Comment: If I were forming a sentence with this sentiment I might say: "I don't like it when a recipe is too easy, I prefer to cook challenging dishes."

Answer (score 1):

"Easy food" is not particularly idiomatic, but it would probably be understood in the context of cooking or preparation. "Easy *meals*" is probably a lot more commonly heard, because a *food* can be a basic, unprepared ingredient, while a *meal* implies some preparation, bringing ingredients together.

"Difficult ingredients" doesn't make sense to me at all. What is difficult about an ingredient? I can only imagine that you mean an ingredient is difficult to use or cook with, so really it is the *recipe* or *preparation* that is difficult. Also, you are saying that you *like* doing this. I don't think anyone likes something that is always difficult - perhaps you mean *challenging*? People like challenges because they enjoy *overcoming* any initial difficulty, so they eventually cease to be 'difficult'.

I would consider saying instead:

- I don't like cooking easy meals. I enjoy trying more challenging recipes.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not sound natural.  In fact, it makes no sense.  The listener is going to have to guess.

Try this:

> I don't like to cook simple **dishes**. I prefer using complex, varied
> ingredients.

> I don't like to cook simple **dishes**. I prefer using complex
> ingredients.

or

> I don't like simple, boring dishes.  Cooking should be intricate and
> sophisticated.  That's why I use a range of complex ingredients.